# Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type '[]'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a third party component that is type []/
But I have a state var that must be type any.

I cannot pass that to the component as it gives this error:
Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type '[]'.

Is there any way to convert the TYPE any[] to [] and then pass it?

This is the component that I cannot touch:

```
 <Component xxx={branchesShow}/>

the type of xxx is this:
    export default interface PropsType {
      xxx?:[];
    }
```

And I do not want to change it or touch it.
it works fine when I do send data directly from api call to it. But since I need to filter it, it gives me type issues....

Comment: You have a third party component that requires an array of length zero?  That’s… weird.  You can use a type assertion but the problem seems to be with that third party component and its problematic typing.  In any case, could you provide a [mre] that demonstrates the error so that any answer will have something concrete to test against?

Comment: That example code isn't quite a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WGk12W) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes the problem was I had this in the type:
branches?:[]

This was not making it array. was just forcing it to be 0 array.
changed to this and it worked.

Thanks...
branches?:Array<{}>;

Answer (score 1):

The full error you are probably getting is this:

```
const myArr = [1,2,3] as any[]
const jsx = <Component xxx={myArr} />
// Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type '[]'.
//  Target allows only 0 element(s) but source may have more.(2322)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false&ssl=12&ssc=38&pln=3&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoCpAD0ljgBMlMUBXAG3mADsYkoWaJHAAKOMAGcAKgE8wwgN4U4KuNXUB+AFxwA2gF0A3BQC+FCplbcMwCNzgBhXJG5JeACjDiJOsREmy8gCUcErkqnBEMKxQ9gA8AHxxAPQJpubkaHYS8CAyAIJQUHAAvHoAjAA0AEyVAMz6cCgSTdwyBhRZ3DlwAFYS1KVwcU7gdm7w6tQlCnmFUCZwqUA)

Note that second line of the error message.

The type `[]` specifically means an array with zero elements. It's delcaring a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) (an array of fixed length with each position having a specific type), not an array of arbitrary length. The type `any[]` is an array type and may have any number of elements, so typescript will not allow it to be assigned here.

Which means that given these props:

```
export default interface PropsType {
  xxx?:[];
}
```

The only values assignable to that prop are an empty array `[]`, or `undefined`. If you try to to assign an array type to that prop typescript will yell at you because that array might not be empty.

Assigning anything besides an empty array is a type error, according to the author of this third party component.

I would advise you to check the documentation of that third party component in order to be sure you are using it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But the issue I have is myArr is not type number. it is type []... kind of NEVER  i believe. So since I have to do some filtering on my array and then setState for my component, my filter is type ANY. then when I do setState it gives this: type 'any[]' is not assignable to type '[]'.     ////// When I used your code

Comment: or this: Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type '[]'.

Comment: this.setState({xxx :myArr );////// xxx is expecting to be type: [] not any not number nothing!

Comment: my problem is xxx must be type []//// it is something my component expects to be that type.

Comment: As I explained `[]` means an empty array. If your state is truly typed that way, and you can't change it, then the only valid value for that is an empty array, which is pretty strange. Please update your question with the actual code that is causing the problem.

Comment: updated Alex thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer to better fit your example, but it's the same problem. You cannot pass an array of many items to a component that is typed to only accept an empty array. And, again, it's really weird that this component works that way. I have no idea why this component is typed that way.